# Why we register custom filter in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why we register custom filter in asp.net mvc ?
I have created a custom filter and that perfectly working without register like `filters.Add(new MyAuthicationFilter());`

What is exactly mean/work of registering the filter like:

```
filters.Add(new MyAuthicationFilter());
```

Comment: Filters need to be registered to be run. Typically you do this with an attribute on a controller/action but registering it globally is just a convenient way of applying it to every action.

Comment: so that we do not have to decorate it on every action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for the purpose that we do not need to decorate it on every action or controller explicitly.

Normally you would do like this:

```
[MyAuthicationFilter]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{

  return View();
}
```

But when you register it in global filters it will be applied to all actions automatically, you now don't need to put attribute on each action.

It is very handy when some filter is to be applied on all actions.

Comment: Thank you. i checked, it working as that you maintained.